# google oath working fine on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I have created google oath code and it is working on localhost but when i move this code on server this is not working i have added both the url localhost and my server url, I have changes the keys can anyone tell me why this is not console.log(response) after login on server

even it is not working on Localhost:8000 but when i run this locathos/abc.html it give me response

Please help me

here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  
    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
    <div id="abc1"> </div>
    <div id="abc2"> </div>
    <div id="abc3"> </div>
    <div id="abc4"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      const CLIENT_ID = '8v1c.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      const API_KEY = '9nuRfJt_skX0Hyc'; 
      const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://script.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'; 
      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects'; 
      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false; 
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
 
      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
      } 
      async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      } 
      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;

        maybeEnableButtons();
      } 
      function maybeEnableButtons() {

        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      } 
      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
          }
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
          await createScript();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
          // when establishing a new session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
          // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
      } 
      function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
          google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
          gapi.client.setToken('');
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      } 
      async function createScript() {
        let response;
        jQuery("#abc1").html(response);
        try {
          const createRequest = {
            resource: {
              title: 'My Script',
            },
          };
          response = await gapi.client.script.projects.create(createRequest);
          const updateContentRequest = {
            scriptId: response.result.scriptId,
            resource: {
              files: [{
                name: 'hello',
                type: 'SERVER_JS',
                source: 'function helloWorld() {\n  console.log("Hello, world!");\n}',
              }, {
                name: 'appsscript',
                type: 'JSON',
                source: '{"timeZone":"America/New_York","' +
                   'exceptionLogging":"CLOUD"}',
              }],
            },
          };
          response = await gapi.client.script.projects.updateContent(updateContentRequest);
          console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
          console.log(response)
          jQuery("#abc2").html(JSON.stringify(response['result']['files'][0]['lastModifyUser']));
          const output = `Script URL: https://script.google.com/d/${response.result.scriptId}/edit`;
          console.log('-------------------------------')
          console.log(output)
          jQuery("#abc3").html(output);
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
```

Comment: Did you double check the URLs , API keys , server permissions etc.

Comment: yes i have check this 10 time

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: I did not get an error